# Integrated Raid Controller Dieds

Tags: hp-proliant, sata

I have an HP ProLiant ml110 G3 with an sata raid controller intrgrated in the motherboard. Few days ago the controller died. Can I use sata ports without the raid?

Comment: Do you need to keep the data on the disks? If yes, replacing the board is probably the only way to save it.

Comment: I have already formatted the disks.

Answer (score 2):

That server is from ~2003. It's really, really old.

See: https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/gethtml.aspx?docname=c04283258

If your onboard SATA controller failed, you could use a PCI-X or PCIe SATA controller to connect the drive backplane to.

However, due to the age of this equipment, I would recommend rebuilding onto something more modern.

Comment: So, I can't use onboard SATA ports as normale ports?